# In IntelliJ (mac), how does one select multiple files in the project window?

Tags: intellij-idea

On a mac, in most apps, holding down cmd allows you to individually select multiple files.  This works in finder and VS Code for example.  In IntelliJ holding down cmd and selecting multiple files doesn't allow this behaviour.  Is there a setting to allow this or is it not possible in IntelliJ?

(you can select multiple files in a list by holding down shift but this selects all the files in a row)

Comment: What keymap is used in "Preferences | Keymap"? Also please attach idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE.

Comment: @y.bedrov thanks, just before I do so, can you check on your own system and see if it works. thank you

Comment: CMD+Click works fine on my Mac.

Comment: ok, thanks, I'll take a look at my keymap & try to work out what is wrong

Comment: Don't you have "Open Files with Single Click" option enabled in Project Tree settings?

Comment: ahhh!  thanks @y.bedrov! that was the one, with Open Files with Single Click turned off I can select multiple files

Comment: When this option is enabled you need to use CMD+Double Click to select file.